# Cookies are not getting stored on localhost subdomains in Safari

Tags: cookies, safari, sveltekit

I have my SvelteKit web app running on http://www.projectname.localhost:3000/, and a Django backend running on http://api.projectname.localhost:8000/. I have configured Django as such:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".projectname.localhost"
```

When I make a login request from the frontend to the backend, there is a `set-cookie` header in the response with the correct session cookie:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.projectname.localhost:3000
Set-Cookie: session_id=some_value_here; Domain=.projectname.localhost; expires=Fri, 10 Mar 2023 13:43:56 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=2592000; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

As far as I can see everything is perfectly fine and this *should* work, and yet the cookie isn't actually stored in Safari, and I am not logged in. However, it works fine in Chrome.

Any idea what might be causing the cookie to not be stored in Safari? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firefox. In the end I had to use `SameSite: 'none'` and `Secure: true` for it to work.

I haven't check how secure this is just yet but being for localhost, I don't think it is a big deal.

Comment: With those settings I can't login at all anymore in Safari :(

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is what worked for me on a very similar scenario. I hope you find the solution soon

Comment: I just realised you have a leading dot in the domain parameter. I think this also caused some problems for me in the past. I suggest you also try by removing the leading dot.

Answer (score 0):

That is an [internet domain suffix](https://pc.net/resources/internet/domain_suffixes) issue. You are using a suffix (or top level domain) of `localhost` and Safari will not save cookies for this unrecognized value.

A while back I had a similar problem for a code example with a `.local` top level domain. It involved adding domains to the local computer's hosts file.

**WORKAROUND**

By updating to a `.com` suffix, the Safari problem was solved, and my example worked.

```
127.0.0.1  www.example.com api.example.com
```

**SUMMARY**

This behaviour is specific to the Safari implementation, but seems to be undocumented by Apple. You will find similar issues if you google for this term, and other mainstream browsers do not have this problem:

```
safari tld cookies
```

**MORE GENERALLY**

The rules around cookies are explained very elegantly in recent updates to [RFC6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/). It describes a public suffix list for top level domains and matching to the web origin. Mostly this is used by user agents to classify some cookies as third party and thus drop them.

In places, recent browser restrictions go beyond the spec. Apple's TLD behaviour is one example. Rejecting cookies unless a real world TLD is used feels reasonable though. I guess it is just something developers like us need to be aware of when designing development setups.

Comment: "Safari will not save cookies for this unrecognized value" - do you have a source for that? It seems unlikely to me  Also that list on that website is definitely not a complete list of all suffixes.

Comment: Not sure if Apple document these things, but there are plenty of occurrences [like this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6514765). Maybe try searching for 'safari tld cookies`.

Comment: While I am not sure about your reasoning of why it's an issue, the workaround works just fine, so I awarded you the bounty.

Comment: I updated my answer based on our discussion. Always good to get the best out of these things and distil our understanding. Cookies are complex things :)